# Identify and reboot workspaces in AWS using Lambda

Tags: python-3.x, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, boto3, amazon-workspaces

I have to write an AWS lambda function in python using boto3. The main aim of the function is that it detects all the unhealthy  workspaces in a directory and reboots the workspaces whose state is unhealthy.

I have created a cloudwatch alarm which triggers the SNS and which in turns triggers the lambda.
I have no idea how to iterate through workspaces in a directory using python which will detect the unhealthy state.
Can anybody please provide me the sample code in python so that I can write the lambda.

Thanks

```js
import json
import boto3

client = boto3.client('workspaces')

def lambda_handler(event, context):
    
    statusCode = 200
    print("Alarm activated")
    DirectoryId = "d-966714f11"
    UnhealthyWorkspace = []
    
    if(DirectoryId == 'd-966714f114'):
        response = client.describe_workspaces(
            WorkspaceIds = (should be in an array)
        )

    us = response["Contents"]

    for i in us:
        if(State == 'Unhealthy'):
            print(i)
            UnhealthyWorkspace.append(i)
    

    response1 = client.reboot_workspaces(
        RebootWorkspaceRequests=[
            {
                'WorkspaceId' : UnhealthyWorkspace
            }
        ]
    )
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [`describe_workspaces()`](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/workspaces.html#WorkSpaces.Client.describe_workspaces) to retrieve a list of all Workspaces.

Then, loop through the list of Workspace and check for: `State = 'UNHEALTHY'`

Comment: Hey, thanks for your response. I have written some code with whatever (updated in the question)  I know in python but I am pretty sure that it won't work. Do you mind to have a look once and suggest what's wrong in it. Thanks.

Comment: I suggest that you try and and see! There's some errors in the flow logic, but you'll figure it out as you debug the code. You can pass `DirectoryId` into `describe_workspaces()`. To loop through the results, use `for workspace in response['Workspaces']:` and then you can refer to elements as `workspace['Status']` and `workspace['WorkspaceId']`. The `reboot_workspaces()` call takes a list of JSON records, not a JSON of lists. Or, just call `reboot_workspaces()` for one instance at a time within the main `for` loop.